# cannot access com.aventstack.extentreports,Bad class file.class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

[image: Error]

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project CluCloud: Compilation failure        
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Saikiran Kondala/Documents/Automation/SIa/selenium/src/main/java/pages/Graphs_CollectionTrends.java:[3,36] cannot access com.aventstack.extentreports.Status
[ERROR]   bad class file: C:\Users\Saikiran Kondala\.m2\repository\com\aventstack\extentreports\5.1.0\extentreports-5.1.0.jar(com/aventstack/extentreports/Status.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I was trying to run the automation code thorugh cmd,I was getting this error